Why will my usercontrol size up but not back down?
I am having an issue with a simple control: When the window loads, it loads the user control correctly. When i maximize, the user control and its contents sizes up as expected. When I restore down, the control does not shrink as expected. The yellow block takes up the whole space but you can scroll down with the mouse wheel.
I have tried various things, namely grids and stack panels. all doing the same. What am I doing wrong?
<Window x:Class="gridtest2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:gridtest2"
        xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:gridtest2.UserControls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" >

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="parentPanelOfControls" Background="Pink">

                <uc:VerticalTextStackControl Text1="ONE" Text2="TWO" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=parentPanelOfControls}"/>

            </StackPanel>
            
        </ScrollViewer>

        
        
    </Grid>
    
</Window>

<UserControl x:Class="gridtest2.UserControls.VerticalTextStackControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="100" Background="Yellow">
    <DockPanel x:Name="MainDockPanel" Background="Aqua" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">

        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0" x:Name="FirstBorder" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DockPanel}, Converter={StaticResource PerCon}, ConverterParameter=0.5}">

            <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1" Background="Yellow"/>

        </Border>

        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0" x:Name="SecondBorder" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DockPanel}, Converter={StaticResource PerCon}, ConverterParameter=0.5}">

            <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock2" Background="Green"/>

        </Border>
        
    </DockPanel>

</UserControl>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows;

namespace gridtest2.Converters
{
    public class PercentageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is double parentWidth && parameter is string percentageStr)
            {
                if (double.TryParse(percentageStr, out double percentage))
                {
                    return parentWidth * percentage;
                }
            }
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

